# flaskapp - Two api resources in two different python scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I have a use case were I need to run multiple python scripts from a same server through flask.

`script1.py` is as below

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class App(Resource):
   def post(self):
       resp = Response('successfully tested')
       return(resp)
        
api.add_resource(App, '/testapp')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(port=6000, host="0.0.0.0", use_reloader=True)
```

Similarly `script2.py` is

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Test(Resource):
   def post(self):
   resp = Response('successfully tested')
   return(resp)
        
api.add_resource(Test, '/test')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(port=5000, host="0.0.0.0", use_reloader=True)
```

Individually when I execute both works as expected, `http://0.0.0.0:5000/test` and `http://0.0.0.0:5000/testapp` works.

But when I configure these scripts as service and try to post the URLs one of them will work and other is failing.

Am I doing right?

Comment: what do you mean as service? Are you using some sort of proxy? Do you want implement a load balancer? The code you show seems not relevant.

Comment: @TheFool I have converted the script as Windows Service. Yes you are right I need to run through loadbalancer but before  that I need both scripts work on local PC. The code is not full there are two API resources with 2 end points "/test" and "/testapp" Will this not work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this as the flask server needs to bind to a port[5000]. You have to run these two scripts on a different port and then you can use Nginx to proxy pass them based on the API rules. Something like below

https://serverfault.com/questions/650117/serving-multiple-proxy-endpoints-under-location-in-nginx
You can use any other reverse proxy also you are not bound to use Nginx.

Comment: Thank you heaps. This helps.

Comment: If this has to be through https SSL 443 how to handle?

Comment: You can simply do the ssl-offloading on the nginx and then forward it to the respective upstream. 
Let you nginx listen for requests on 443 and based on your resource like `/api/v1 or api/v2` you can forward to 5000 service1 or 5001 service2